# how to get binance current klines from 00:00UTC till now for whole available tickers at ones?

Tags: python, api, algorithmic-trading, binance, cryptocurrency

Is there a way to get binance current day kline for '1day' timeframe, not for past 24h, but for current day started at 00:00UTC, with one request (without looping every ticker). Like get_ticker() in python, but it returns 24h change, I need klines for whole available tickers.

to prevent duplicates. websockets is not acceptable, because, data is not comming properly, I am losing some data. according to my tests (my problem - I have around 900 tickers to check, if I pass all of them to websockets and start to listen, some tickers are updating faster than others, i think thats because some data is not recieved and handled, not because they are not traded at that time.

or if there is a good example of how to achieve this with websockets, would be great.
here is what i expect to get as response:
example,

```
{
    'BTCUSDT': [43000,45000,40000,41000], # [open, high, low, close]
    'ADAUSDT': ...,
    ...
}
```

thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but when you choose `interval = 1d`, you will receive klines data starting at 00:00 UTC. The most recent entry will start (open time) last night at midnight and continue until the current time. If you call the API at 6pm (UTC), you will then receive one entry reaching from midnight to 6pm.

Comment: Thanks, but i need many tickers at ones(maybe 1000 of them at one). Without need of iteration through all of them one by one with get_klines()